# Как проверить наличие данных в таблице по конкретному параметру? (язык GO)

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, golang

На данный момент имею следующую таблицу:

merchant_id | order_id | amount

Логика приложения заключается в том, что я создаю мерчантов с уникальным именем, затем эти мерчанты создают неограниченное количество ордеров, id которых может иметь одинаковое значение

На данный момент я создаю мерчантов и имею этот код

```
row := db.QueryRow("select * from deals where merchant_id = $1", mr.MerchantID)
err = row.Scan(&mr.MerchantID)
if err != nil {
    result1, _ := db.Exec("insert into deals (merchant_id, order_id, blocked_amount, charged_amount) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
        mr.MerchantID, "", 0, 0)
    fmt.Println(result1.RowsAffected())
} else {
    fmt.Println("merchantID exists, try another")
```

Я рассчитывал на то, что Query поможет мне определить есть ли данный мерчант в таблице, если есть - он говори что такой уже существует, если нет - он создает его и записывает в таблицу, но на данный момент этот код регистрирует мерчантов с одинаковым именем

Сначала думал поставить ограничение уникальности на мерчантов, но это тогда дальше не смогу сделать неуникальные ордеры и к тому же мне не нужна паника

Видел что люди пользуются exists, но как применить его в GO в VisualStudio не понял

Answer (score 0):

Если бы вы распечатали текст ошибки внутри `if`-а, то увидели бы, что ошибка вовсе не `sql.ErrNoRows`. Вам `select` возвращает три значения, а в `Scan` вы запрашиваете всего один. Соответственно, у вас там ошибка `sql: expected 3 destination arguments in Scan, not 1`

Либо в `select` запрашивайте одно значение (например, `"select merchant_id from deals where merchant_id = $1"`), либо в `Scan` передавайте три параметра.

Работающий пример

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    database, err :=
        sql.Open("sqlite3", "./some.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    statement, _ :=
        database.Prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deals (merchant_id varchar, order_id varchar, amount real)")
    statement.Exec()
    statement, _ =
        database.Prepare("INSERT INTO deals VALUES (?, ?,?)")
    statement.Exec("Merchant", "order112345", 123.45)
    row := database.QueryRow("SELECT merchant_id FROM deals where merchant_id = ?", "Merchant")
    var mrchnt string
    // var orderid string
    // var amnt float64
    err = row.Scan(&mrchnt)
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        fmt.Println("No rows: ", err.Error())
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unexpected error: ", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(mrchnt)
    }

    row = database.QueryRow("SELECT merchant_id FROM deals where merchant_id = ?", "Merchant2")
    err = row.Scan(&mrchnt)
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        fmt.Println("No rows: ", err.Error())
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unexpected error: ", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(mrchnt)
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Merchant
No rows:  sql: no rows in result setMerchant
```

Функция для проверки существования кортежаза по значеню одного из полей:

```
func CheckRowExists(db *sql.DB, table, column string, value interface{}) (bool, error) {
    query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT %s FROM %s where %s = ? limit 1", column, table, column)
    row := db.QueryRow(query, value)
    var tmp interface{}
    err := row.Scan(&tmp)
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return false, nil
    }
    if err == nil {
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, err
}
```

Для параметров используется знак `?`. Это нотация `sqlite`. Вам в постгресе нужно использовать `$1`.